# MarkLogic - CORS with REST API

Tags: api, rest, semantic-web, marklogic

I have a MarkLogic-based web application which pulls data from two sources, a document store and a triple store both hosted on my MarkLogic server. The app uses MarkLogic's built-in REST APIs to access these data stores. The document store's REST API is running on port 8003 and the triple store's REST API is on port 8007. The application is hosted on the modules database of the document store. Now, when I make a REST API call to pull triple data, I get an exception saying the 'access-control-allow-origin' header has not been set at the server side. I would like to know how I can set it up so I get 'access-control-allow-origin' as '*' in all responses from the REST API. I have read the documentation on xdmp:add-response-headers, but I'm not able to figure out where I can use it correctly. All help is much appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why not keep the documents and triples in the same database? The ability to do that is one of MarkLogic's strengths.

The built-in REST API endpoints don't seem to support any mechanism for adding arbitrary response headers. However you should be able to add your own headers when writing a REST extension: https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/extensions

For the built-in endpoints you might consider routing requests through another app-server layer, or a transparent reverse proxy. Either way the goal would be to re-route requests so that the browser thinks both REST API instances are on the same server.